# NtCreateEvent returns ERROR_BAD_PATHNAME (161)

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

**Background**

I am trying to set an event with a given name to determine if the application has already queued a given task.

I am using `NtCreateEvent` and `NtOpenEvent`, so I wrote 2 wrapper functions for each.

**NtCreateEvent**

```
HANDLE CreateEvent(PCHAR EventName) {
    UNICODE_STRING uString;
    Rtl::InitUnicodeString(&uString, 
        Str::ConvertAnsiToUnicode(EventName));

    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjAttributes;
    InitializeObjectAttributes(&ObjAttributes,
        &uString, 0, NULL, 0);

    HANDLE hEvent;
    NTSTATUS Status = NtCreateEvent(&hEvent, EVENT_MODIFY_STATE, &ObjAttributes, 1, 0);
    if (NT_SUCCESS(Status)) {
        if (Status != STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_EXISTS) {
            Nt::SetLastError(ERROR_SUCCESS);
        } else {
            Nt::SetLastError(ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS);
        }
    }
    return hEvent;
}
```

**NtOpenEvent**

```
BOOL OpenEvent(PCHAR EventName) {
    UNICODE_STRING uString;
    Rtl::InitUnicodeString(&uString, 
        Str::ConvertAnsiToUnicode(EventName));

    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjAttributes;
    InitializeObjectAttributes(&ObjAttributes,
        &uString, 0, NULL, 0);

    HANDLE hEvent;
    if (NT_SUCCESS(NtOpenEvent(&hEvent, EVENT_QUERY_STATE, &ObjAttributes))) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

**Notes**

My check is along these lines

```
if (!Nt::OpenEvent("Global\\taskname")) {
    // do something

    Nt::CreateEvent("Global\\taskname");
} else {
    // work with the task
}
```

**Question**

What am I doing wrong? How does the `EventName` have a `BAD_PATHNAME`?

Comment: because path is really invalid. you need use `"\\BaseNamedObjects\\taskname"`

Comment: Oh right, so its the same prefix as for Mutants. Gotcha! Msdn should really document it along with the API, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566423(v=vs.85).aspx (not present anywhere)

Comment: as separate note - you not need use 2 api calls `NtOpenEvent` and `NtCreateEvent` - you need use single call `NtCreateEvent` with `OBJ_OPENIF` in attributes. and not use ansi charsets. just use Unicode and not convert

Comment: Since this question is tagged [tag:winapi], why aren't you using the Windows API ([CreateEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396.aspx) and [OpenEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684305.aspx))? If nothing else, the [kernel object namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382954.aspx) as exposed by the Windows API are documented.